# How to hide hover message on jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jsp, grid, jqgrid, mousehover

I made a button in each cell on jqGrid.
But I wanna hide hover message(tag content)
please check below this,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B0o5.png)

jqGrid hover message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In colModel properties there is a property called title. By default it is true. Set it to false to do what you want